# Can I safely run badblocks in read-only mode on a mounted drive?

Tags: filesystems, mount, hard-disk, disk, badblocks

I have /dev/sda mounted on /, as the root partition. Can I safely run `badblocks` in read-only mode on this device? Will it show false positives/negatives because it's mounted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read-only is just that - reading from the disk. It will pick up sector read errors but (obviously) not sector write errors.

Categorically, it is safe to run on a device that is being used a mounted filesystem.

With respect to possible false positives, block IO is not "managed", i.e. there are no reader/writer locks. So there is no interaction between `badblocks` and the filesystem layer.

Comment: Will it get any false positives possibly because the OS might be using the device while badblocks is scanning?

Comment: @Markasoftware no, you shouldn't. At least not on normal disks (maybe it's possible—no idea—on something complicated, like a SAN)